# Why can't I access jakarta.persistence package in v3.0?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

When I upgraded to EclipseLink 3 by referenceing `org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:3.0.3` instead of 2.7 which I had
before, I can no longer use any classes in the jakarta.persistence package, even indirectly.

The errors I see are:

> Cannot resolve method 'setHint' in 'org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaQuery'

and

> Cannot access jakarta.persistence.TypedQuery

I don't understand why. It **seems** that use of the jakarta.persistence-api module is not being allowed but my application doesn't use any classes from that module directly so I don't think my app should open it.

Comment: Are you using a modular project? Did you add the right `requires` statement to module-info.java?

Comment: I'm not using a modular project and I'm not sure what I should define for `requires`

Comment: If you're not using a modular project, then my suggestion doesn't apply.